# How to get window decorations to work correctly?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, fglrx, window-buttons, titlebar

I'm currently using Natty (fully up-to-date) and there is one small issue that I can't quite figure out: My computer has an ATi Radeon Mobility HD 4xxx series card so I used the proprietary FLGRX driver (because I need the performance gain). This wouldn't be a problem except that all non-maximized windows in Unity don't update their title bars.

When I hover over the window decorations, they don't highlight like they are supposed to. Nautilus (which shows the current directory in its title bar) only shows either a) the name of the folder I first opened it to; or b) if I minimize the window and pull it back up, it will update to the folder I'm currently in but still won't update on-the-fly.

I've always made due with it because it didn't bother me too much, but now the them that I'm using has updated where the window decorators only show their function on hover, so it has become something of a usability issue. Is this a known bug? Is there a solution to fix this? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Found this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/781384) in Launchpad that seems to be what I'm experiencing. If anyone has any news on this or a developer's perspective would still love to hear back.

EDIT2: The theme I am using is Ambiance Evolution, however, the issue exists across ALL themes for me (Ambiance, Radiance, elementary, Ambiance Evolution, etc.)